# Problem running pick and place application tutorial

Tags: ros, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am trying to run the tutorial in

http://devel.iri.upc.edu/docs/roswiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29Writing%2820%29a%2820%29Simple%2820%29Pick%2820%29and%2820%29Place%2820%29Application.html

However, I get an error saying: Call to segmentation service failed

This occurs when it looks for the tabletop in the very beginning. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31265/problem-running-pick-and-place-application-tutorial/) by [alexanderjyuen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2045/alexanderjyuen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the robot looking at the table/object?  Segmentation won't succeed otherwise.  If you're in Fuerte or Groovy, you can use interactive manipulation to position your robot, see http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/Tutorials/The%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Autonomous%20Demo/

Also, this shouldn't have been a problem back in April 2012, but recently if you were using Fuerte + Kinect, there was a launch misconfiguration that was killing segmentation that is now fixed.

Sorry not to answer in a very timely fashion.  All my ROS answers emails were getting spam-filtered. :P

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-05-24**:
I've got the same problem recently, but there was no such problem before. The default setting is to use the stereo camera and I've write a simple node to make PR2 look down. But the problem still exists. How to fix this problem? Thanks

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-05-25**:
You're using the stereo camera and looking at the table and it says Call to segmentation service failed?  Any other error messages around it?  Which ROS distro are you using?

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-05-25**:
I've checked the pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch, and the value of arg stereo is true, which will set thetabletop_segmentation_points_input as narrow_stereo_textured/points2. I put the error messages here: http://notepad.cc/dedoucle19 and the brief description is below. My ROS distro is Fuerte

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-05-25**:
The object segmentation service can segment out the table. The INFO shows that "Step 4 done" and "Table computed". But after that, there seemed to be some internal problems which threw out the error message "Call to segmentation service failed", and then the tabletop_segmentation node died.

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-05-28**:
Hrm.  That's odd.  Fuerte debians, latest version?  Are you using shadow-fixed or public repos?  What version of Ubuntu?  64-bit or 32-bit?  I just tried using pr2_table_object.launch, both stereo:=true and stereo:=false, and both worked fine on my laptop.

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-05-28**:
There have been some build-farm compilation issues with compile flags lately, that might be causing the undefined-symbol problems you're seeing.  Try just compiling and using object_manipulation and pr2_object_manipulation from source.

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-05-30**:
I'm using Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and the package is installed using apt-get. I've already upgrade all the package to the latest version. I don't know what is the difference between using shadow-fixed or public repos. Also, what is build-farm compilation issues with compile flags lately mean?

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-05-30**:
I'm guessing you're using the public repos (http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu) then.  When http://ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html shows FbinP64 for perception_pcl having a green box (mouseover the green box should read ros/Public 1.2.4) then the new release of perception_pcl will be done building.

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-05-30**:
Once that happens, check that pr2_object_manipulation is also green, and then try sudo apt-get upgrade to get the newest debs.  Then hopefully things will work again.  If not then comment here again.